# Rails 3 : Use model method while using sum()

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to rails. I am trying to figure out how to use model method inside the `sum()` sql function. I tried searching for the solution but couldn't find one. Here's the code snippet :

```
SUM(indents.total_payable_amount_paid) AS sum_comm_t_amount_payable_paid
```

I want to use method called `total_payable_amount_paid` defined inside `indent` model. But it always gives an error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column indents.total_payable_amount_paid does not exist.
```

So what's the solution for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Whatever yo put inside `SUM` needs to be the _name_ of the column in your model's table, that's why you are getting that error.

Comment: I know. I don't have that field in the table instead i have a method that just returns a value. Is there any possible solution other than adding a new field to the table?

Comment: I added an answer that might help you, but i'm curious: Why would you like to add a value like that? If you share more of your code it will be easier to provide better solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `SUM` (which i assume it's in a query **string**) takes `indents.total_payable_amount_paid` as part of that string.

To avoid that you could use **string interpolation** to set the value you want, like this:

```ruby
"SUM(#{indents.total_payable_amount_paid}) AS sum_comm_t_amount_payable_paid"
```

So, lets say `indents.total_payable_amount_paid` returns `250`, then the above code will generate this string:

```ruby
"SUM(250) AS sum_comm_t_amount_payable_paid"
```

But, using `SUM` will make no effect, since you are giving one value, so you can accomplish the same thing without it:

```ruby
"#{indents.total_payable_amount_paid AS sum_comm_t_amount_payable_paid"
#=> "250 AS sum_comm_t_amount_payable_paid"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I have found another way to solve this by using only db columns. I guess what i was trying to accomplish earlier(i.e this question) doesn't make any sense.